# Binding Javadoc generation to mvn package

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm new to Maven (first university assignment), and I'm trying to find help wherever I can.

I'm supposed to configure Maven in order for it to compile, create a `JAR` file, and generate `javadoc` when using the `mvn package` command.

I've tried adding javadoc goals to the `pom.xml` file, but nothing seems to force javadoc generation when using the `package` target.

Do any of you know if it is at all possible to do this ? If so, how ?

EDIT : I tried the below solution, and after reading more documentation, I think what I'm trying to do is to bind the `mvn javadoc:javadoc` execution to the `package` phase.

(I'm happy to delete the question if documentation on this exact issue is elsewhere, I have'nt found any though)

`pom.xml` file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>coo</groupId>
  <artifactId>TP0</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>

  <name>TP0</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>https://www.boredbutton.com/</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Javadoc -->
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.1</version>
           <configuration>
             <reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/docs</reportOutputDirectory>
             <destDir>docs</destDir>
             <nohelp>true</nohelp>
             <!-- <additionalOptions>-html5</additionalOptions> -->
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
            <mainClass>student.MainStudent</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
      </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure a goal and a phase:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javadoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>execution1</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin> 
        </plugins>
</build>
```